# Google Endpoints with iOS Client : User has to sign in every time

Tags: ios, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm developing an iOS Application that uses Google Endpoints API. In order to authorise the requests, the user must sign in with his Gmail account on the first screen. I've managed to get this to work but the problem is that the user has to log in every single time he launches the app. Is there a way to have the session last a bit longer? For example, when using the Facebook SDK for iOS, once the user logs in with Facebook, the session stays active until the user explicitly logs out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with what I consider to be a hack that solves this problem.

**Step 1**: After the user signs in with his/her Gmail account, save the authentication object properties to NSUserDefaults.

```
@objc(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)
    func finishedWithAuth(viewController :GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch , auth:GTMOAuth2Authentication,error:NSError!){

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);

        if error != nil {

            println("Authentication Failure: \(error.localizedDescription)");

        }else{

            GoogleEndpointAssistant.saveGTMOAuth2AuthenticationToUserDefaults(auth)

            setAuthentication(auth)

        }
```

*GoogleEndpointAssistant.swift*

```
class func saveGTMOAuth2AuthenticationToUserDefaults(auth : GTMOAuth2Authentication!){

            assert(auth.parameters != nil)
            assert(auth.parameters.count > 0)

            auth.parameters.setValue(auth.tokenURL.absoluteString, forKey: "token_url")
            auth.parameters.setValue(auth.redirectURI, forKey: "redirect_url")

            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
            defaults.setObject(auth.parameters, forKey: GMTOAuth2AuthenticationKey)

        }
```

**Step 2**: Rebuild the auth object in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        if let auth : GTMOAuth2Authentication = GoogleEndpointAssistant.rebuildGTMOAuth2AuthenticationFromUserDefaults(){

            setAuthentication(auth)
        }

    }
```

*GoogleEndpointAssistant.swift*

```
class func rebuildGTMOAuth2AuthenticationFromUserDefaults()->GTMOAuth2Authentication?{

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
        if let parameters  = defaults.dictionaryForKey(GMTOAuth2AuthenticationKey){

            let serviceProvider = parameters["serviceProvider"] as? String
            let tokenURL = NSURL(string:parameters["token_url"] as String)
            let redirectURL = parameters["redirect_url"] as String


            let auth : GTMOAuth2Authentication = GTMOAuth2Authentication.authenticationWithServiceProvider(
                serviceProvider,
                tokenURL: tokenURL,
                redirectURI: redirectURL,
                clientID: GoogleCloudEndPointClientID,
                clientSecret: GoogleCloudEndPointClientSecret) as GTMOAuth2Authentication

            auth.userEmail = parameters["email"] as String
            auth.userID = parameters["userID"] as String
            auth.userEmailIsVerified = parameters["isVerified"] as String
            auth.scope = parameters["scope"] as String
            auth.code = parameters["code"] as String
            auth.tokenType = parameters["token_type"] as String
            auth.expiresIn = (parameters["expires_in"] as NSNumber).longValue
            auth.refreshToken = parameters["refresh_token"] as String
            auth.accessToken = parameters["access_token"] as String

            return auth
        }
            return nil 
    }
```

Comment: Yeah using the signInSilently method from GIDSignIn.sharedIntance() should fix that issue. But in my case it fails because it doesn't find anything the in KeyChain, where all the auth data should be saved when you first signedIn normally. There is a thread related to this here: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/82